# Saying 'Are you Satisfied?' in Japanese: 満足ですか or 満ち足りですか

Tags: word-choice, words, definitions

I'm not quite sure what the difference between (1) 満足ですか and (2) 満ち足りですか - Do they both mean "Are you satisfied?"

I'm trying to say "Satisfied" in the sense of being satisfied with one's life and accomplishments. Is there a better way of saying this? Are (1) and (2) interchangeable?

Comment: If you want to translate "satisfied" in the sense of being satisfied with one's life, you must use "満ち足りている".

Answer (score 1):

Not interchangeable in general. Xに満足していますか is a neutral and common way to ask whether someone is satisfied with something - food, finance, life etc. 満足ですか is not too different. 満ち足りていますか is typically used to ask someone's spiritual well being, at least in a modern setting.

If you want to ask about "being satisfied with one's life and accomplishment", you will need to make it explicit by saying something like あなたは人生に満足していますか. あなたの人生は満ち足りていますか is possible, but again, it sounds like it focuses onto spiritual life almost exclusively.

満ち足りですか is ungrammatical.